# Django Forms - How to link a check box to a boolean field

Tags: django, django-forms

python 3.6
django 1.11 (haven't updated it yet)

I'm wanting to add a True/False checkbox to a form. I see how to do it on a html page and on the form itself, but the two aren't linking. Whenever I check the True box, the field that represents the checkbox is false.

HTML

```
    <div class='form-group'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="donation-repeat" id="donation-repeat_id">
    <label for="donation-repeat_id">Repeat my donation (yearly)</label><br>
    </div>
```

Forms.py

```
class DonationCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    recurring_donation = forms.BooleanField(required = False,label = 'donation-repeat_id')
    class Meta:
        model = Donation
        fields = ['total','recurring_donation']   

    def clean_recurring_donation(self):
        print('we are cleaning now')
        print(self.cleaned_data)
        recurring_donation =  self.cleaned_data['recurring_donation']
        print('recurring_donation1 ', recurring_donation)
        return recurring_donation
```

Views.py

```
class DonationCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = DonationCreateForm
    template_name = 'donations/create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        donation_form = form.save(commit=False)
```

However, I am always getting this output
`recurring_donation1 False`

Regardless of whether or not I have checked the box.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your form to the data coming from your request. In your view

```
 form = DonationCreationForm(request.POST)
```

You must also use  tag in your template in addition  to submit button.

Comment: I'm using a classbased view and have set the form_class to be the DonationCreateForm. I thought this would bind it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

Give the following a try: remove 'required=False'

good luck!